# Maven Spark Source Code Build Fails in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: maven, apache-spark, pyspark, build

I am trying to build Spark 3.1.1 source code using mvn build as below:

./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package

However build fails without giving any proper error as below

killed 13456 "${MVN_BIN}" -DzincPort=${ZINC_PORT} "$@"

Any help is much appreciated.

My environment is as below:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Java : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1G; support was removed in 8.0
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
spark Version : Spark 3.1.1

Comment: For further information, I have posted the messages from terminal in which I executed the mvn build command as below:

Comment: [INFO] Using incremental compilation using Mixed compile order
[INFO] Compiler bridge file: /home/hduser/.sbt/1.0/zinc/org.scala-sbt/org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.12-1.3.1-bin_2.12.10__52.0-1.3.1_20191012T045515.jar
[INFO] compiler plugin: BasicArtifact(com.github.ghik,silencer-plugin_2.12.10,1.6.0,null)
[INFO] Compiling 326 Scala sources and 103 Java sources to /home/hduser/Desktop/spark-3.1.1/sql/catalyst/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
./build/mvn: line 164: 28389 Killed                  "${MVN_BIN}" -DzincPort=${ZINC_PORT} "$@"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. After investigation, it was confirmed that the Linux oom-killer killed the process and the reason was insufficient memory.

Maven Log:

```
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:4.5.6:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-hive-thriftserver_2.12 ---
[INFO] Using incremental compilation using Mixed compile order
[INFO] Compiler bridge file: /home/tianshuang/.sbt/1.0/zinc/org.scala-sbt/org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.12-1.5.8-bin_2.12.15__52.0-1.5.8_20211211T222914.jar
[INFO] compiler plugin: BasicArtifact(com.github.ghik,silencer-plugin_2.12.15,1.7.6,null)
[INFO] compiling 27 Scala sources and 86 Java sources to /home/tianshuang/IdeaProjects/latest/spark/sql/hive-thriftserver/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
./build/mvn: line 185:  8772 Killed                  "${MVN_BIN}" "$@"
```

Cmd:

```sh
dmesg -T | grep -i kill
```

Output:

```
[Wed Apr 13 22:07:44 2022] fsnotifier invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[Wed Apr 13 22:07:44 2022]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
[Wed Apr 13 22:07:44 2022] [   1862]  1000  1862   114275       95   110592      117             0 gsd-rfkill
[Wed Apr 13 22:07:44 2022] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=java,pid=8772,uid=1000
[Wed Apr 13 22:07:44 2022] Out of memory: Killed process 8772 (java) total-vm:15551840kB, anon-rss:4862120kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:10256kB oom_score_adj:0
```